# How can I force a 4-digit year regardless of locale?

Tags: java, jodatime

For my Android app I'm using Joda Time to print localized Date, as follows:

```
String date = DateTimeFormat.shortDate().print(new LocalDate());
```

But this gives me a two-digit year.

So, how can I do to display the year as a four-digit number regardless of the current user Locale?
And, how can I append a 0 before day or month if they are < 10, again, regardless of the current user `Locale`?

Comment: I'd guess don't use `shortDate()` but rather provide your own date format or use another provided format that does what you want.

Comment: which version of Joda are you using? I do not see any method `shortDate()` method in `DateTime`

Comment: Is it `DateTimeFormat`?

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually want to use the locale settings, if you want to force yyyy, MM and dd rather than yy, M and d. If you're not going to make it an idiomatic local representation, why not just go the whole hog and specify the pattern fully?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code snippet, it will give you the date in your format:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy").print(new LocalDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

### You're going to have create your own mapping.

Here's what already exists: Joda Time has a method [`DateTimeFormat.patternForStyle`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#patternForStyle(java.lang.String%2C%20java.util.Locale)), which delegates to the patterns specified by the JDK in [`java.text.DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html). See [Using Predefined Formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html), which provides the following table:

```
Style       U.S. Locale             French Locale
DEFAULT     Jun 30, 2009            30 juin 2009
SHORT       6/30/09                 30/06/09
MEDIUM      Jun 30, 2009            30 juin 2009
LONG        June 30, 2009           30 juin 2009
FULL        Tuesday, June 30, 2009  mardi 30 juin 2009
```

You specify which `Locale` specific format you in `patternForStyle` by using `S`, `M`, `L`, `F`, and `-` to leave it blank. So, in your case, it sounds like you want date only, so use:

```
DateTimeFormat.patternForStyle("S-", locale);
```

#### Unfortunately, this option will result in a TWO digit year.

So, either do all of that, or **create your own map` of DateTimeFormatters for this purpose. Something like:

```
public class DateFormatterProvider {
  private final Map<Locale, DateTimeFormatter> formatterMap = new HashMap<>();

  public DateFormatterProvider() {
    formatterMap.put(Locale.US, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    formatterMap.put(Locale.FRENCH, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy"));
    // etc.
  }
}
```